# What is the name of this plot?

Tags: ggplot2, data-visualization, ggtimeseries

[image]

I would like to redo this plot, which was published in one of the newspaper about Covid 19 death toll. I am not sure what kind of graph is this, I am assuming this is percent stacked area plot.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a streamgraph of some kind. So, a streamgraph is a type of stacked area chart. It represents the evolution of a numeric variable for several groups. Areas are usually displayed around a central axis, and edges are rounded to give a flowing shape.

I found it hard to install streamgraph from git hub repository, however, there is a ggplot alternative available called "ggTimeSeries". Below is the link for streamgraph R documentation.

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/streamgraph.html